# Can't remove margin/padding on footer

Tags: css, html

I'm having trouble removing a phantom margin/padding in my footer.  I've created a simple site to illustrate the problem:

http://autodatanetwork.com/index-simple.html

Specifically I'm having a tough time removing the green ~15px padding at the very bottom of the site.  Strangely if I add a padding to the footer of up to 15px nothing happens.  If increase the footer padding beyond that the footer will grow, but the "phantom" footer disappears.  It's as if there is some min-height on the footer.  Thanks in advance for your help.

The html is below where I've added some inline styles for debugging purposes.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="cs">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Test simple</title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="keywords" content="">
        <meta name="author" content="David Kohout & Tomáš Lach - www.tomaslach.cz">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/apple-touch-icon.png">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" media="screen,projection">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/print.css" media="print">
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/custom.js"></script>
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
    </head>
    <body style = "background: #F00; padding: 0px; margin: 0px;">
        <header>                       
        </header>
        <div id="content" style=" background:#0FF; padding-bottom: 1000px;">                
        </div>
        <!-- / #content -->      
        <footer style = "background: #000; padding-bottom: 5px; margin-bottom: 0px; " >
            <div class="wrap clearFix" style  = "background: #00F "  >
            </div>
        </footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the culprit (line 36):

```
.clearFix:after {
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

The `.` character is causing the gap. Change `content: "."` to `content: ""`.

Alternatively, since you are explicitly setting a height of `0`, you could also just add `overflow: hidden` to hide the gap.

As a side note, I'd suggest changing the class to:

```
.clearfix:after {
    content: '';
    clear: both;
    display: table;
}
```